# strings with only ascii characters php

Tags: php, string, ascii

I have set of strings where some of them are made of non-ascii characters.
How do I get strings with only ascii characters using a php script.

Thanks a lot in advance for any guidance..

Comment: do you want to ignore the entire string if they have non-ascii characters, ignore just the characters, or replace the characters?

Comment: ASCII chars including non-printable characters?

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

echo preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/', '', 'Standard ASCII and some gärbägè');

?>
```

Comment: you can still get characters you are not checking for. always whitelist! match for things you know you want. it is much less error prone.

Comment: @gcb - No you don't. In fact, this already is a whitelist -- "reject everything that is not a printable ASCII character". If it were a blacklist, it would say -- "reject these specific non-printable or non-ASCII characters and accept everything else". You have it backwards.

Comment: you are correct. missed the `^` there and assumed the hex codes were for things out of printable range. will blame it on lack of coffee :) thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest option is to use the [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function (if the `iconv` extension is available), using either the `//IGNORE` or `//TRANSLIT` option (see the documentation), if the behavior suits your needs.

Comment: Hello Everybody, I want only printable ASCII charecters.

Comment: iconv only works on encoding it understand now. let's say you have the string `a^Xb` (`^X` being a control char). iconv will never remove it, because `^X` is not part of any encoding it understands. it used to remove it with //IGNORE, but if you follow the bugs on the top comment for iconv you will see that is not the case anymore.